# JavaFX FXML create component/control

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

How to create custom control like `Pagination` , `ProgressIndicator` etc.

Using JavaFX SceneBuilder Custom component can be created but its FXML contains all hierarchy of tags . But `Pagination` does not contains hierarchy of tags (ex button , list etc) , it contains single tag `<pagination>` with some attribute .

So my question is that how to create components like pagination that does not show its internal tag hierarchy ?

Answer (score 0):

I asked for a tutorial some time ago, but unfortunately the issue is still open:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090885

Basically you'll need to:

- provide a class which extends Control and defines the interface
- provide a subclass of [SkinBase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SkinBase.html) for this control to provide the content
- provide a CSS (now optionally, I think)